# Can we use how many times the way it's been used in the first sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

> 1. She's talking on the phone about how her neighbor died, as if **how many times** she's talked about the incident so far isn't enough.
> 2. She's talking on the phone about how her neighbor died, as if the number of times she's talked about the incident so far isn't enough.

Is the first sentence grammatically correct, and does it mean the same as the second sentence means?

Comment: No, the first sentence is incorrect - or at least very awkward, since I don't have a simple explanation for why it's wrong.

Comment: How you would you construct a sentence that means what the first sentence means?

Comment: I would use the second sentence.  To me, it means what the first sentence seems to mean.

Comment: *how many times* in your first sentence does not make sense to me at all, so I call it an incorrect sentence. furthermore, although *isn't enough* in your second sentence may be acceptable, I'd like to use *aren't* there.

Comment: @Abbasi - the subject of the last clause in the sentence is **the number**, which is singular, so **isn't** is the correct form.

Comment: @stangdon, Although the word *number* can be treated as singular or plural depending on the context, in this case your are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence

> She's talking on the phone about how her neighbor died, as if *how many times* she's talked about the incident so far isn't enough.

is awkward at best.

> how may times

is in the pattern of a question asking the number of times, yet I believe you want to express "she's" talked about it ***many times***

> She's talking on the phone about how her neighbor died, as if *the number of times* she's talked about the incident so far *wasn't* enough.
>
> She's talking on the phone about how her neighbor died *again*, *so many times* she's talked about the incident so far *hasn't been* enough.

Answer (score 1):

In a "first sentence", it's fine to mention that someone is doing something too much, or too often.  But not with the examples you provide.

A more natural sentence would be:

> She's talking on the phone *again* about how her neighbor died, as if she hasn't *already* talked about it *enough*.

The "again" and "already" imply she's done it previously, and the "enough" implies that I think the number of times she's already talked about it should be *sufficient*.

You can also specify the number of times, if it's relevant.

> He's trying *again* to get on the Olympic curling team, as if *five times* wasn't enough.

Comment: Would you go so far as to say the first sentence is wrong?

Comment: @lekonchekon I don't know if it's *grammatically* incorrect.  If I had to guess I'd say it's fine.  But instead of "how many times" I think it's more natural to say "the number of times".  But given the context both feel too *wordy*, like someone giving a college lecture rather than casual conversation.